# What is "ol plug-it-in" as a charge approach?

Tags: connector, charger, charging

I'm reading an article which is about [wearable smart watches](http://www.phonearena.com/news/To-wearable-or-not-to-wearable_id64018). In the following context author says Sony SmartWatch 3 uses `ol' plug-it-in` approach for charging, I never heard about this approach? Is `ol' plug-it-in` a kind of cable?

> To their credit, many of the manufacturers have made charging a
>   non-micro USB charging affair, though Motorola’s Moto 360 is probably
>   the most handsome execution of the idea. Sony, for reasons unknown has
>   chosen the **ol' plug-it-in** approach with the Smartwatch 3. None of
>   these methods would matter to me if didn’t have to go through the
>   exercise on a daily basis though.

Answer (score 1):

`ol'` is an abbreviation for `old`, the author means it doesn't use wireless charging.